# If $a,b,c \in \mathbb R$, $a+b+c=2$, $a^2-b^2-c^2=12$, find the difference between the max and min possible value of c.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math

I couldn't find the answer to this on Google, but I did find a similar problem on Art of Problem Solving. The question was exactly same except that in the question $$a^2+b^2+c^2=12$$

But I couldn't incorporate the solution in my question because in mine only $b^2$ and $c^2$ are negative and $a^2$ has a different sign.

The answer given is 25, but I don't know how this answer came.

Comment: If there are no restrictions on $a,b$,  all values of $c$ are possible except $c=2$. Hence there is no minimum or maximum value for $c$. Please check the statement of the problem.

Comment: @quasi, does it make a difference if I put the condition that a,b,c are distinct?

Comment: No. Also, I don't think you should change the problem in a way that would invalidate a posted answer. Just accept a posted answer and move on.

Comment: @quasi, I forgot to mention that the answer given is 25.

Comment: Given where? Where is the problem from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assume $c \neq 2$, otherwise you get a contradiction. Since $a+b=2-c$ and $(a+b)(a-b)=12+c^2$ then $a-b=(12+c^2)/(2-c)$, so you can find $a$ and $b$. This tells you any $c \neq 2$ will do, so the question does not make much sense.

Answer (score 1):

Hint

The general idea is to eliminate one of $a,b$

$$12=(2-b-c)^2-b^2-c^2=4-4b-4c+2bc$$

$$\iff8+4b=2bc-4c$$

$$b=4(2+c)/2(c-2)$$

So, $c$ can assume any real value $\ne2$